# How to get the Subject line from a chat message to the bot? MS-Teams

Tags: .net, sdk, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams

[image]

MS Teams .net Bot SDK does not contain a property for 'Subject' and this seems to be disregarded by the bot even with RSC permissions to read all messages.

`IMessageActivity` and `IActivity`

I thought it may be added as an attachment with the html supporting it but this is also not the case.

*(Secondary issue is the attachment is not created unless the text contained has a level of formatting)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the 'Subject' line from a chat message in Microsoft Teams using the .NET Bot SDK.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Answer (score 0):

In many chatbot frameworks and platforms, including some versions of OpenAI's GPT models, the subject line or any metadata associated with a message is not typically used for generating responses. The models are usually designed to process and generate responses based on the content of the message rather than its metadata like subject lines.

However, the way to handle metadata or subject lines can vary depending on the specific chatbot implementation you're using. If you're working with a custom implementation or a specific platform, you should consult the documentation or support resources provided by that platform for instructions on how to access metadata or subject lines associated with chat messages.

For instance, if you are using a web framework to interact with the OpenAI API, the subject line (if it's included in the API request) might be accessible as a field in the JSON object you use to send the message to the API. Always refer to the official documentation of the specific API or library you are using for the most accurate and up-to-date information.strong text

Comment: Thanks @Sophie Turner for your response, the meta data does not get passed in this way that is visible to me with the request. I cannot see any properties that would support this either in the Bot SDK. I have updated the title to show I am referring to the MS-Teams bot SDK to help focus on the specific issue.